# Strange Fibonacci results using a list function

Tags: php, fibonacci

I came across a very nice Fibonacci series implementation but I am having trouble understanding how exactly it works. Here are the two implementations I have tried in order to figure out the issue:

```
<?php

fibo(1000);
fibo2(1000);

function fibo($n){
    list($a, $b) = [0, 1];

    while($a<=$n){
        echo $a . " ";
        list($a, $b) = [$b, $a + $b];
    }
    echo "\n";
}

function fibo2($n){
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;

    while($a<=$n){
        echo $a . " ";
        $a = $b;
        $b = $a + $b;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

The above two functions produce the following results respectively:
fibo:  0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 
fibo2: 0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512

Could you please explain why the different results occur?

Comment: Well you already noticed something "strange". The 2nd one is *not* a Fibonacci sequence. Just plain ole doubling.

Comment: @GetSet If you stick numbers in the second one you will see that the fibonacci series emerge. Problem is I don't get why. Why is the first one working and the second one not? Does this have to do with mutability/immutability of variables?

Comment: It as to do with the fact that `$a` loses its value when it's set to `$b`'s value in the 2nd implementation. In the 1st implementation, the use of `list()` makes those inputs *parameters* and thus their values aren't lost when it comes to the assignment. In this case, the value of `$a` can correctly be used in the assignment when defining `$b`.

Comment: Thanks @GetSet! This clears things up.

Comment: Yeah the 2nd one just wasn't a fib sequence. The 2nd one could be useful though for listing the place values for binary numbers. Excluding the zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation repeat:

It as to do with the fact that `$a` loses its value when it's set to `$b`'s value in the 2nd implementation. In the 1st implementation, the use of `list()` makes those inputs *parameters* and thus their values aren't lost when it comes to the assignment. In this case for list(), the value of `$a` can correctly be used in the assignment when defining `$b`.

For example:

```
function fibo2($n){
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;

    while($a<=$n){
        echo $a . " ";
        $save_a = $a;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $save_a + $b;
    }
    echo "\n";
}

fibo2(1000);
```

This corrects the 2nd implementation.

With the output being:

`0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987`